# How remove conky manager from Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, conky

I would like to ask how to completely remove conky manager from Linux Mint.

I used the following script [link](https://github.com/zcot/conky-manager2/blob/add-1.10-support/HOWTOBUILD.md) and `sudo apt-get --purge remove conky conky-all` but unsuccessfully

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to remove the `conky-all` package.

```bsh
sudo apt-get --purge remove conky conky-all
```

This is a thread with more information.(https://askubuntu.com/questions/938495/how-can-i-delete-conky-from-my-system/938509)

Answer (score 0):

Did some light searching as I'm not too aquainted with Linux but this seemed to work for most people:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove conky conky-all
```

Hopefully it works for you as well!

Comment: I think this script only solves the removal of the conky, but not the conky manager application. I used the following script [link](https://github.com/zcot/conky-manager2/blob/add-1.10-support/HOWTOBUILD.md) but unsuccessfully